# Prevent HTML to be displayed from $_GET method

Tags: php, html, code-injection, exploit

I'm currently working on a user management system.
I have the register and sign-in page among other sites, that all use the $_GET function. After experimenting around a bit I noticed that you can print HTML code from the GET parameters when you exactly know what you are doing. There is probably a way to exploit this by using the onerror in an img tag e.g.

How can I prevent this from happening?

The URL: `users.php?s=login&mail=">%20<img%20src=%27../images/notification_bell.png%27%20width=%2725px%27>`

What it displays:
[image]
And my code:

```
print ' <form action="' .$url. '" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="a" value="login"/>
    
                <b><label for="mail">E-Mail:</label></b>
                <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail" maxlength="50" value="' .$mail. '" required><br><br>
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Just sanitize the url parameters before displaying them. In this case you can use filter_var() or smth similar to achieve this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: It's called [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) and yes there are lots of ways to exploit unsanitized user input that's displayed. Never trust any user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `htmlspecialchars` to convert user-defined characters into web-safe code. https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars

also, maybe you could use `filter_var` to validate the email and simply unset it if it's invalid. https://www.php.net/filter_var

Comment: Would it then look like this:
`if(!empty($_GET["mail"]))
             $mail = htmlspecialchars($_GET["mail"]);` ?
Seems to work

Comment: it's your choice how you use it. I personally always escape values directly at the point where they are used - not before. so I would replace `$mail` with `htmlspecialchars($mail)` in your print statement.